# Failure on allocating memory in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I have C implementation of an algorithm that includes shared library. The performance of the shared library is considerably different in C and C++ (performing much better in C++). Therefore, I have changed the shared library parts of the C implementation (*Imp-1*) into C++ (*Imp-2*) while keeping the rest of it same. I have compiled *Imp-1* and *Imp-2* by using gcc and g++ in Linux, respectively. In small sized problems both *Imp-1* and *Imp-2* perform exactly same. However, in a same large sized problem while *Imp-1* solves it without any problem, *Imp-2* returns **std::bad_alloc** error. Interestingly, this error occurs when the memory usage increases to 4GB where the available memory is 35GB.

Why this error occurs? (Compiler, operating system, compiler option, etc.)

Best Regards.

Comment: Does the C implementation work fine for the same large size problems? Or have you only tested the small problems in your benchmark? Where C++ throws a `std::bad_alloc` C often returns a null pointer, which might go unnoticed for a while when an explicit check is missing. Also it would be interesting to know from where a std::bad_alloc is thrown. `std::vector` for example often uses an exponential scheme for resizing, so it might grow to 4GB even before  all this space is need. If you use `std::vector::resize` at some places, it might work for some larger sizes even on 32bit systems.

Comment: I am running the codes on 64bit system (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6). I have checked the Makefile, I added -m64 option while compiling the C++ implementation with g++. C implementation works fine independent from the instance (small or large). I gave same instance (it is a large instance) to both implementations, while C ended up fine, C++ returns std::bad_alloc error at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your gcc is a 64 bit compiler where as g++ is a 32 bit compiler. Even if you are running on a 32 bit system, unless you compile your program with a 64 bit compiler, your program cannot fully leverage the 64 bit addressing capabilities which would result a bad_alloc as you are experiencing if you want to address more than 4GB.

The reason I am confident that you are running a 32 bit compiled program on a 64 bit is the 4GB limit. Generally speaking, the memory is split as User/Kernal Space and on a 32 bit system the entire 4GB is not available, usually it is between 2GB and 3GB. As you can address the entire 4GB it seems you are running a 32 bit program on a 64 bit environment.

Comment: I am running the codes on 64bit system (Red Hat Linux), and -m64 option is enabled during the compilation with g++. How can I assure that I am compiling with 64bit g++.

Comment: @Gokhan: Good question. Run `objdump -f <YourExecutable>|grep file`. If you get something like `file format elf64-x86-64`, its a 64 bit executable, else if you get `file format elf32-i386`, its a 32 bit executable.